# swiftからobjective-cの呼び出しについて

Tags: swift, xcode

下記test.mのsetupAppCWithMediaKeyをview_test.swiftのコード上より呼び出そうとしてい
ますがview_test.swiftの第３番めの指定で
"launchOptions:0x00000100"の指定でビルドエラーが出てしまいます。
objective-cの内容をswiftから呼び出す時のキャストについて教えていただければ助かります。

/* test.m */

```
+(void)setupAppCWithMediaKey:(NSString*)mk_
                      option:(NSUInteger)option_
               launchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions_;
```

/* view_test.swift */

```
appCCloud.setupAppCWithMediaKey("xxxxxxxx",option:0x00000000, launchOptions:0x00000100)
```

ビルドエラー内容
タイプの期待値引数の型を 'のInt'を変換できません'[NSObjectの：ANYOBJECT]！

Comment: `NSDictionary`型の引数に、整数値を代入しようとしている、イージーミスではないのですか？

Comment: appCCloud.setupAppCWithMediaKey("xxxxxx",option:(0x00000000|0x00000100))
のように記述することで解決しましたありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

以下のように記述することで解決しました。

```
appCCloud.setupAppCWithMediaKey("xxxxxx",option:(0x00000000|0x00000100))
```

---

*この投稿は @mat2 さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*